# adjective describing a personal difficulty

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives

Trying to think of a word that describes an action that is easily accomplished by most people yet said person cannot.

Example:

> Since fifth grade, I have played the bass in my school orchestra, and yet somehow I still can’t hit that high F sharp. I know I am not the best bass player, and definitely have my weaknesses, which include that `____` note.

Comment: As a Brit, I would probably say something like "that wretched note" in your particular case.

Comment: Blasted, miserable, fucking, god-forsaken, doomed, confounded.

Answer (score 3):

Your example invites ***elusive***: tending to evade grasp or pursuit.

PS: I think this addresses the question topic and your example, but it doesn't necessarily relate to the "easily accomplished by most people yet said person cannot" part.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following suggestions

Foible

Idiosyncrasy

Peculiarity

Comment: The OP needs an adjective to satisfy the requirement in the context posted.

Comment: All these terms provide exactly that context to my mind - a personal weakness or trait

Comment: I agree, but the text given requires an adjective.  "That idiosyncratic note", "that peculiar note" work though.  A bit pedantic in my case, I'll admit.

Comment: Ste is right: these terms are nouns; OP needs an adjective.

Comment: Easily solved: idiosyncratic peculiar

Answer (score 0):

The word that fits most is **unmanageable**.

> I know I am not the best bass player, and definitely have my weaknesses, which include that **unmanageable** note.

Comment: Or "unobtainable".

Answer (score -1):

**Facile**: done or achieved in a way that is too easy.

This is a subtle usage of the word. Facile is a derogative way of saying something is easy, even if it has not yet been achieved.